# Pending vs. left vs. remaining

Tags: differences

When should one use *pending*, as opposed to *left* or *remaining*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Left" and "remaining" are synonyms.

> I have only four eggs left.
>
> There are only four eggs remaining in
>   the refrigerator.

You can also use "remaining" as an adjective, as in

> The remaining eggs were rotten.

You couldn't use "left" in that construction.

"Pending" is a different matter. It refers to something that is about to happen or is in suspension for the moment.

> Their pending divorce weighed heavily
>   on the children.

It can also be a synonym for "until", as in

> Pending a trip to the grocery store,
>   we will not be able to make omelets
>   for everyone, since we only have four
>   eggs left.

Comment: @Robusto_ Fascinating. I wonder **why** _left_ can't be used as an attributive participial adjective whereas _remaining_ can? Offhand, I can't think of many participles that can't be used thus. Also, what part of speech would you say _left_ is in _I have only four eggs left_, please - assuming you think it's sensible to classify it separately. Admittedly, it doesn't seem to fill a traditional adjective role, but, as with _we are three dollars over_, it hardly seems adverbial. Were it not for the _over_ analogue, we could probably argue that it is a participle.

Comment: I would guess it's because of the confusion between *left* as past tense of the transitive form of the berb *leave* ("four eggs left") and *left* as adj. meaning "on the left side. Even if the ambiguity is explicitly dealt with, it just sounds awkward: "The stolen eggs were sorely missed, as the left eggs were mostly rotten." One would almost certainly substitute "remaining" in that case, as the listener would still have to work to parse the meaning of *left* in that context.

Comment: Might be worthwhile mentioning leftover which can be used in "The leftover eggs were rotten."