# When to use "pending" vs. "impending"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Although someone has previously answered a question as to the [difference between "pending" and impending"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12124/pending-vs-impending-are-they-synonyms), I'm still struggling on when to use which word, and if one is preferred in a more formal context.

For example, I was talking about the upcoming FIFA World Cup Semifinal Match, and that I was awaiting one team's *"impending victory"*.  Was that an accurate use? Should I have used *"pending victory"*?

Comment: As stated in the accepted answer to the other question, they mean different things. So, the formal/informal context is not relevant. You probably do mean "impending" when talking about the football. To my ear, "pending" would suggest that the result is predetermined (and might come across as a way of implying skulduggery), whereas "impending" comes across as a confident prediction.

Comment: What is with all this “formal” thing people keep mentioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending is indicative of something currently being decided, while impending is indicative of something's result about to become known or about to be decided.

Hope that helps.